# Add Perl module relative to script

Tags: perl, module, relative-path

im trying to add the module [File-Copy-Recursive](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/File-Copy-Recursive/File/Copy/Recursive.html) to my script as i have done with another module already, but when i try to use it i get an error i can not explain:

```
use lib "./cpan";
use Recursive qw(dircopy);
dircopy($path1, $path2);
```

the error i get is: Undefined subroutine &main::dircopy called at ...

I don't understand it, the module clearly has the function dircopy in it.

Comment: did you try with complete package name `use File::Copy::Recursive`

Comment: The module is not in the standard lib i have installed and i dont want to rely on that either. i downloaded the module from cpan and placed it in the /cpan folder where my script is located.

Comment: Ok, so i got it running by using

    File::Copy::Recursive::dircopy($path1, $path2);

in my code.
I dont know why it works only this way though.
Maybe someone can comment on that.

Comment: `:: `is nothing but a folder structure you will have `FILE\COPY\Recursive.pm` file under your `cpan` directory,so to maintain the package name with standard format.instead you can use `use Recursive` function(as u posted ) but u should have Recursive.pm file under cpan directory. hope i am clear, if you want more i will go ahead and put 1answer instead of comment.

Comment: @JamieFlowers There's nothing wrong with installing modules this way, but you should at least be aware that there are easier ways to do it. On linux/unix most people would use the 'cpan' or 'cpanm' programs to automatically download and install a module with all the required dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other answers have already stated, this isn't working because you've moved the module's location in the include directory from `File/Copy/Recursive.pm` to just `Recursive.pm`.

Here's *why* that doesn't work:

A Perl *module* (file with a `.pm` extension) and a Perl *package* (collection of code under a specific namespace) are two completely different things.  Normally, we'll put a package into a module which happens to have the same name, but this is really just to help us humans maintain our sanity.  `perl` doesn't care one way or the other - one module can contain multiple packages, one package can be split across multiple files, and the names of the packages and the modules can be completely unrelated for all `perl` cares.

But, still... there's that convention of using the same name for both, which the `use` command exploits to make things a little more convenient.  Behind the scenes, `use Module;` means `require Module.pm; Module->import;` - note that it calls import on the *module* name, not the name of the package contained within the module!

And that's the key to your issue.  Even though you've moved the file out of the `File/Copy/` directory, its contents still specify `package File::Copy::Recursive`, so that's where all of its code ends up.  `use Recursive` attempts to call `Recursive->import`, which doesn't exist, so nothing gets imported.  The `dircopy` function would be imported by `File::Copy::Recursive->import`, but that never gets called.

So, yeah.  Move `./cpan/Recursive.pm` to `./cpan/File/Copy/Recursive.pm` so that the package name and the module name will match up again and sanity will be restored.  (If you've been paying attention, you should be able to come up with at least two or three other ways to get this working, but moving the file to the proper place under `./cpan` really is your best option if you need to keep the `File::Copy::Recursive` source in a subdirectory of your project's code.)

Answer (score 2):

Use FindBin for relative lib path:

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/./cpan";
use File::Copy::Recursive;
```

And you have to keep the whole 'tree' under ./cpan and the use line have to remain the same.

Files under ./cpan dir:

```
 find ./cpan/
 ./cpan/File/Copy/Recursive.pm
```

Comment: Hm, i dont see the difference, as i said it was already working with another module. I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The module name in Perl comes not only from the path, but also from its `package` declaration. You installed the module to `./cpan`, but the package name specified is still `File::Copy::Recursive`.